# using scanf_s to write into a const char* memory

Tags: c++

I have a program as shown below :
This one works fine why? isn't it supposed to be constant for each of the characters? why am I able to overwrite it?

input: "Test" (Any String that is shorter dan 8 last byte reserved for null-terminated)

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

  int main()
{

  const char itemss[8] = "1234567";
  const char* item = items;

  scanf_s("%s", item, 8);
  printf(item);

  return 0;
}
```

but when I try to change the code to this :

this one doesn't work, the code is the same as the above code but this one cause segmentation fault, string literal is const char[] (in this case const char[8]) so it should be no different than the code above right? my guess is this code below allocated in read-only memory but then again the code above also use const.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {  
        const char* item = "1234567";

        scanf_s("%s", item, 8);
        printf(item);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can't write into `const char *`. `const` means that it's not writable.

Comment: both are Undefined Behavior